# How to i make my python files go back to normal?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

So i'm using python3.4, but decided to try out 2.7. Bad idea.
When i installed python 2 all of my python files started opening with python 2 IDLE, which wasn't really my plan. I then decided to uninstall python 2 again and i figured that now it should go back to normal. It didn't.

The files now wanted to open as pyWin instead of python 3. I changed the "open as" and tried put it to idle. Now the problem is that it always opens as idle, and there is no icon. Usually you get the option "open as idle" when you right click on it, and you get the console when you double click. Now it opens as idle even if i double click on it, which i don't want. Now i don't know how to make it go back to normal. I tried searching on the internet, but it only told me to set the "open as" to idle, which doesn't do what i want.

I don't know if this got messy, let me know if there is anything i need to clearify.

[image]
  [image]

Comment: This sounds like you just need to go into Windows settings and clear the default application for .py files. If this is the case, try http://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/how-to-set-default-programs-and-file-types-in-windows-10/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the problem is the interpreter. On a Linux machine i'd suggest du edit/add the shebang line.

But this looks like Windows to me. I guess the easiest solution would be to reinstallt Python3.X in the prefered version. This should overwrite the PATH variables.

EDIT: I havent had this problem yet, this solution just sounds logicle to me.

Comment: What will happend to my modules if i reinstall?

Comment: Oh, thats a brilliant question. To be honest, i have no clue. You better ask this to a windows user... I left windows behind for years, sorry.

Comment: Maybe the python-installer provides a "repair" function?

Comment: The python installer wont't touch any third party modules.

Comment: So i reinstalled python and even took this as an oppertunity to upgrade to 3.6, now it all runs as it's supposed to. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

Re-set the file association. In a `cmd.exe` window, give the following commands.

```
assoc .py=Python.File
ftype Python.File="C:\path\to\python3.exe" "%1" %*
```

In the `ftype` command, you should use the proper path to your Python 3 executable.